# vim: visual block select till character on every line

Tags: vim

```
[
  {name: 'John'},
  {name: 'Plasmody'},
  {name: 'Kugelschreiber'},
  {name: 'Sarrah'},
]
```

If I am on the `J` and do `C-v jjjj`, how can I select till the second single quote? I am search something that works like `C-v jjjj $` or at least a way to yank/replace/delete till the quote.

Comment: I don't think Vim can do this. You may have better luck with other editors that have multiple-cursor support, such as Sublime Text or Atom.

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

But you can simply use the so-called "dot-formula":

```
ci'foo<Esc>
j.
j.
j.
```

or a nice substitution.

Comment: Instead of repeating `j.` many times, you can also select lines with `V` and run `:'<,'>g/^/normal .`

Comment: Yeah, or use an ad-hoc range. I went with the simplest method.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a plugin you can use https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors and then select the lines and then press `<C-n>`. You will get a cursor on each line and can then select and edit the text inside all the quotes at the same time.